# Как задать начальную высоту контрола в окне, но чтобы при изменении размера окна размер контрола менялся?

Tags: c#, wpf, resize, controls

Хочу сделать окно с полем ввода. При открытии окна высота поля ввода `TextBox` должна быть строго 100 px, а размер окна должен подстроиться под высоту `TextBox`. Но после открытия окна, если менять его размеры, высота `TextBox` тоже должна меняться.

Способ задать высоту окна не подходит, потому что тогда высота `TextBox` при разных темах Windows будет разная.

```
<Window SizeToContent="Height">
    <TextBox Margin="20"
             InitialHeight="100" />
</Window>
```

**UPD:**

Упрощаем задачу: как задать, чтобы высота **рабочей области** окна при открытии была 100 px, но потом менялась вместе с размером окна?

```
<Window SizeToContent="Height">
    <Grid Height="100" Background="Yellow" />
</Window>
```

Comment: Знаете что такое Grid? Нет? А стоило бы. Это один из основных компонентов, который адаптирует контент под размер окна. Задайте ему грамотное положение и размеры и все будет как надо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, не нужно умничать. Приведите реальный пример того, что хотели сказать. Есть миллион вариантов использования контрола Grid.

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/4.2.php вот вам помощь)

Comment: И каким образом это мне поможет? Куда прописывать высоту 100 px? Гриду? RowDefinition? Полю ввода? В любом случае если я укажу высоту, она уже не будет меняться вместе с окном.

Comment: Уважаемый, я не умничаю, я вам лишь даю подсказку. Если не хотите дальше эту подсказку обрабатывать, то  что тогда вы ожидаете от нас? [Вот](https://hastebin.com/atemahitix.xml) самый стандартный пример грида, который подстроит TextBox под половину. Установив окну `Height="430"` - вы получите размер бокса по высоте = 200 и дальше при изменении размера вы будете менять и сам бокс. Да, это не совсем то, что вы хотите, но и не ясны ваши цели. Кто будет терпеть "танцующее" окно, которое в один момент с одной высотой, а в другой совершенно другой? Только пользователь решает, какой размер его окна.

Comment: 1. Высота поля ввода = 100, Margin сверху+снизу = 40, откуда взялось 430? 2. Откуда взялась высота 200? 3. Почему окно должно получиться "танцующим"? Прочитайте внимательней вопрос и все станет ясно.

Comment: Можно задать высоту окна = нужной изначально высоте TextBox + Margin сверху и снизу + высота заголовка окна + высота верхней и нижней рамки окна (с тенью). Но если реальная верстка куда сложнее описанной в вопросе, то формула получится многоэтажной. Ну и еще вопрос вычисления размеров заголовка и рамок окна. Поэтому я сразу написал, что этот способ не подходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Первое решение оказалось сложным:**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox.Height = 100;

    double firstHeight = 0;

    this.SizeChanged += (s, e) => // TODO: отписаться от события
    {
        if (firstHeight == 0)
            firstHeight = this.Height;
        else if (this.Height != firstHeight)
            textBox.Height = double.NaN;
    }
}
```

**Второе решение получилось намного изящней:**

```
<Window SizeToContent="Height">
    <TextBox Margin="20" Height="100" />
</Window>
```

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += (s, e) =>
    {
        ClearValue(SizeToContentProperty);  // this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
        textBox.ClearValue(HeightProperty); // textBox.Height = double.NaN;
    };
}
```

Comment: Кмк, второе решение вполне себе, но я бы переписал его в виде AP, чтобы можно было декларативно цеплять на любой `FrameworkElement`

Comment: Что значит AP? И как это сделать?

Comment: Attached Property